# Display geo coordinates on Bing Maps via share-able http requests

Tags: http, request, bing-maps

I have a set of geo coordinates and I'd like to build a URL string(http request), once shared can be followed to view Bing maps with a polyline connecting all the geo coordinates and push pin at each geo coordinate. I did that this is possible with Google Maps http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index.html. Something like that for Bing Maps would be ideal.

I have looked through the Bing Maps api at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701702.aspx, but not find any share-able http request building documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating this over the last week, I was not able to confirm it, but it appears as though http request for this functionality to Bing Maps is unsupported.